# No PHP errors displayed in php 7 but in php 5.6 on local dev with AMPPS

Tags: php, error-reporting, php-ini, php-7.1

I tried for hours to solve this problem, but I need some help...

I am using [AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com/) for local development. I am using php 7.1.
Unfortunately I don't get any error reporting, when I mistype something.

I double or tripple checked the php ini file for error reporting:
I have the following values set in the php ini file of the version (opened via ampps):

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

I also execute

```
phpinfo();
```

(works only if nothing is broken)
and I get the following:

```
Apache Version  Apache/2.4.25 (Unix) PHP/7.1.2 mod_wsgi/4.5.11 Python/3.6 OpenSSL/1.0.1p
PHP Version 7.1.2

Directive | Local Value | Master Value
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  On  On
error_reporting 30719 32767
```

the only thing I could think of is that this constant for the error reporting is wrong on the local value (found the following [here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php))

```
32767   E_ALL (integer) All errors and warnings, as supported, except of level E_STRICT prior to PHP 5.4.0. 32767 in PHP 5.4.x, 30719 in PHP 5.3.x, 6143 in PHP 5.2.x, 2047 previously
```

When I switch to php 5.6 in AMPPS I get e correct error. With php 7 I just get a blank page with no information.
It drives me crazy O.o

Is there anything else which I am missing?

Cheers

__ Edit:
So parsing errors are my main problem!

Comment: There is both a php.ini for cli and gui/apache, are you changing the correct one? Do errors display when you run a php script in command prompt? Are errors getting logged to a log file?

Comment: Ok nice points to look for the problem. I will do that. Just to clarify: what do you mean by running a script in command prompt? Running it from the terminal?
And yes I have a local wordpress installation and I enabled debug logging. The problem is, that nothing is executed if it finds a parsing error (which is not displayed) > so de debug log file is not updated either...

Comment: I looked for this file: Loaded Configuration File in phpinfo(); and it is indeed the one with my error settings on. So I guess it is the right one.

Comment: Yes, I mean if you run a problem script from the terminal at the command prompt with the command `php myscript.php` do any errors show up. Just create a small script, separate from Wordpress, with an error in it. Try running it from both the terminal and the web browser and see if you see an error in either place.